# How do I hide the Next button when the last page is shown?

Tags: reactjs, axios, components, jsx, hide

I am getting data from an API for a particular page using the below code:

```
const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(true); 
const [ showsData, setShowsData ] = useState(undefined);
const [ newData, setNewData ] = useState(undefined);
const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(props.match.params.pageno);

useEffect(() => {
    
        async function fetchData() {
            try {
                const { data } = await axios.get('http://api.tvmaze.com/shows?page=' +pageNumber);
                setShowsData(data);
                setLoading(false);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
        
        fetchData();
    }, [ pageNumber ]);
```

Now, for pagination I am trying to hide the next button until the last page, I can get the last page by fetching data for the page after it. If it returns empty [], I will know that I found the last page and can hide the next button. To do this I created another useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    
        async function fetchData() {
            try {
                
                const { data } = await axios.get('http://api.tvmaze.com/shows?page=' +pageNumber+1);
                setNewData(data);
                setLoading(false);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
        
        fetchData();
    }, [ pageNumber ]);
```

To hide the next button I am doing the following:

```
   { newData!==[] && <Link className='showlink' to {`/shows/page/${parseInt(pageNumber)+1}`}>
                        Next
                    </Link>}
```

This does not work and the next button is shown even after the last page. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Set initial state of `newData` to an empty `Array`.

```
const [ newData, setNewData ] = useState([]);
```

Comment: I made the change, I still see the next button on the last page

Comment: Try checking length of the `newData`. Change the condition to `newData.length > 0`

Comment: Tried that too, one more issue I am seeing is that when I type in the URL of a page beyond 100, it shows me the values of the 0 page. Not sure why

Comment: Can you share a live link for better understanding?